# ¿Como obtener variables desde get por php?

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas tardes amigos de stackoverflow.

Tengo esta duda, en mi codigo php tengo una url con variables gets:

http://localhost/prueba/back-comentarios/chgpw.php?email=ejemplo@gmail.com&code=c69aa9b6b202ac65c0537372f3350075

Quisiera tomar es las variables email y code y por medio del formulario que les presentare adelante quiero enviar esas variables conjunto con el password y el check password hacia el archivo updatePassword.php

```
<?php 
$email = var_dump($_GET['email']);
$code = var_dump($_GET['code']);
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/bootstrap.css">
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
        <style>body{padding-top:40px;padding-bottom:40px;background-color:#eee}.form-signin{max-width:330px;padding:15px;margin:0 auto}.form-signin .checkbox,.form-signin .form-signin-heading{margin-bottom:10px}.form-signin .checkbox{font-weight:400}.form-signin .form-control{position:relative;height:auto;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:10px;font-size:16px}.form-signin .form-control:focus{z-index:2}.form-signin .signin{margin-bottom:-1px;border-bottom-right-radius:0;border-bottom-left-radius:0}.form-signin input[type=password]{margin-bottom:10px;border-top-left-radius:0;border-top-right-radius:0}</style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <section> 
        <form class="form-signin" class="container" method="POST" action = "updatePassword.php">
            <h2 class="form-signin-heading text-uppercase">Recuperar Clave</h2>
            <label for="password" class="sr-only">Ingrese su nueva clave</label>
            <input type="password"  id="password" name="password" class="form-control signin" placeholder="Ingrese su nueva clave" required autofocus>
            <label for="password-check" class="sr-only">Clave</label>
            <input type="password" id="password-check" name="password-check" class="form-control" placeholder="Valide su clave" required>       
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php $email ?>">
            <input type="hidden" name="<?php $code ?>">
            <p class="help-block">Su nueva clave debe contener al menos 8 caracteres.</p>       
            <hr>


<button class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block" type="submit">Cambiar clave</button>
<!--                <a href="index.php" class="btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block">&Aacute;tras</a> -->
            </form>
        </section> <!-- /container -->

        <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Aqui el updatePassword.php :

```
    <?php
require_once("connection.php");

if (isset($_POST['email']) and isset($_POST['code'])) {
    echo "tomaron los POSTs";
    $checkmail = $connect->query("SELECT email FROM users WHERE email='$email' AND lost!='' ");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($checkmail);
    if ($count) {
        if (isset($_POST['password']) and isset($_POST['password-check'])) {
            $password = md5($_POST['password']);
            $password_check = md5($_POST['password-check']);
            if ($password==$password_check) {
                    $inserted = $connect->query("UPDATE users SET lost='', password = '$password' WHERE email='$email' ");
                }   
            if ($inserted) {
                echo "<h1>Se cambio con exito tu password</h1> <a href='index.php'> Regresa a home </a> ";
                header("index.php");
            }else {

                echo "<h1>No se creo el cambio</h1> <a href='index.php'>Regresa a home </a> ";
            }
        }
    }
}else{
    echo "No se hace un coño";
 }?>
```

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema?

Comment: El error empieza desde tu formulario donde tus dos *inputs hidden*, ya que no has pasado el atributo `value` , es decir, su valor, también te falta los `echo` en tu `php`, prueba así a ver: `<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>" />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque están las variables, al no mostrar, dar salida o imprimir el contenido el resultado que te da es este:

```
<input type="hidden" name="">
<input type="hidden" name="">
```

Prueba a cambiar:

```
<input type="hidden" name="<?php $email ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="<?php $code ?>">
```

Por:

```
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email ?>">
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="<?php echo $code ?>">
```

> Como indica D.Bulten en el comentario falta también añadir los values.

Y al inicio elimina los *var_dump* y deja solo la asignación de las variables.

Cambia:

```
<?php 
$email = var_dump($_GET['email']);
$code  = var_dump($_GET['code']);
?>
```

Por:

```
<?php 
$email = $_GET['email'];
$code  = $_GET['code'];
?>
```

Comment: @D.Bulten Cierto, lo leí rápido y no me fijé que no estaba usando las variables en los values.

Comment: Buen aporte, mis 1+

Comment: Excelente aporte ahora si me envian los gets